# Bootstrap 4 Popper.js : How to dynamically update the content of the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I am trying to update the HTML content of a popup from `popper.js` with html content coming back in ajax from the server.

The popup is created on page load. In the HTML :

```
<a id="upvote-637" title="Popup" 
   data-toggle="popover" 
   data-content="<ul><li>item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul>" 
   data-remote="true" 
   href="/posts/637/upvote">
       Link text
</a>
```

In the Javascript :

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  trigger: 'hover', 
  html: true
});
```

I would like to update the content dynamically. I tried :

```
// This is working to Toggle display
$("#upvote-637").popover('toggle') 
// This is not working to update the content  dynamically 
$("#upvote-637").popover('toggle')[0].dataset.content = "TEST";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tippy.js which uses Popper.js as its core engine, just like Tooltip.js does.

With Tippy.js it's easier (it was built to easily [load data via ajax](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/ajax/)):

```
tippy('#ajax-tippy', {
  content: 'Loading...',
  animateFill: false,
  animation: 'fade',
  flipOnUpdate: true,
  onShow(instance) {
    // call ajax; then use instance.setContent(responseText);
  },
})
```